# Unset the "please wait" in drupal commerce

Tags: forms, ajax, commerce, theming

I've got a product with different taxonomy like "S" "M" "L".
When you change the size in the display product, it shows the ajax div
"Please wait..."
I've tried

```
function bartik_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
unset($form['attributes']['field_size']['#ajax']['progress']['message']);
}
```

If I have a look at it with dms($form) I see attributes -> field_size -> #ajax -> callback(commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_attributes_refresh)

There is not message. How can I get rid of it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Save yourself the headache of tracking down and overriding the JS responsible for adding the loader, and just hide it with CSS

Comment: A display:none is always quick eheh but what if I would like to change it? How could I do it?

Comment: @Clive No reason to use CSS on stuff that Drupal already have made configurable ;)

Comment: @googletorp Good point, I was just being lazy ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way could be to hide it with CSS, but what is displayed by Drupal is actually configurable. The throbber with the *Please wait...* message is the default behavior but you can change it to a number of things. What you need to look at is the [`#ajax['progress']`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax) attribute.

Usually `#ajax['progress']` is not set in the form, and Drupal will add the default throbber with the *Please wait...* message in the JavaScript that handle the ajax request. The solution it quite simple, all you need to do is to set it like this:

```
$form['element']['#ajax']['progress'] = array('type' => 'throbber');
```

It will kill the message and only show the throbber. There are a number of ways to configure what Drupal does to show the user progress - you can read all about it in the link above.

Comment: do you mean like this? function bartik_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { $form['element']['#ajax']['progress'] = array('type' => 'throbber'); }, it does not work :( the hook is right because i'm testing it with $form['submit']['#attributes']['title'] = $form['submit']['#attributes']['value'] = t(''); and it empty the submit button

Comment: @SydBarrett The above code is example code - element should be replaced with the name of the element that has the `#ajax` property.

Comment: Hey man, it works, I've changed ['element'] with ['attribute']['name_of_my_field'] . Now I can override it as I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, but in comment mistake: not 'attribute' - 'attributes'.

```
function bartik_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['attributes']['field_NAME']['#ajax']['progress'] = array('type' => 'throbber');
}
```